# If scenario_selected==2 & 3 then the function should return the post id with minimum likes and maximum Likes Respectively

Tags: python-2.7, instagram-api

Function 'get_user_posts' should return the post id of the post with least number of likes if the scenario_selected by the user is 2 and should return post with maximum likes if scenario_selected == 3

```
def get_user_posts(user_name):
        user_details = get_user_id(user_name)
        request_url = (BASE_URL + 'users/%s/media/recent/?access_token=%s') % (user_details[1], APP_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        recent_posts = requests.get(request_url).json()
        if recent_posts['meta']['code'] == 200:
            if len(recent_posts['data']):
                print 'Select a Scrnario to like a post : \n 1. Like a random post \n 2. Like a post with minimum likes \n 3. Like a post with maximum likes \n 4. Like a post with Caption containing particular text'
                scenario_selected = int(raw_input('Select a Scenario : '))
                total_posts = len(recent_posts['data'])
                if scenario_selected==1:
                    random_post = randint(0, total_posts - 1)
                    like_post(recent_posts['data'][random_post]['id'])
                elif scenario_selected==2:
                    id=total_posts
                    print total_posts
                    id=total_posts
                    for data in recent_posts:
                        while id<=total_posts:
                            id=id-1
                            return min(recent_posts['data'][id]['likes']['count'])
                elif scenario_selected==3:
                     return max(recent_posts['data'][id]['likes']['count'])

                else:
                    print 'Please enter a valid input'
            else:
                print '%s don\'t have a recent post' % (user_details[0])
        else:
            print '%s don\'t have a recent post' % (user_details[0])
            return 0
```

Comment: what is your question? is your code not working? what is the status?

Comment: yes code is working only if selected_scenario==1 but not working for 2 or 3